# Javascript pasting url in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want a javascript code which can do the following :
After loading my site ie : www.xyz.com the url in the browser should change to www.abc.com.
But dont load www.abc.com. it will usually load www.xyz.com and after loading javascript will just past the url ie : www.abc.com.
It usually means masking.

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Comment: You can't do that (for security reasons).  The browser won't let you change the domain in the URL bar without reloading a page from that domain.  You can mess with the URL path using the history API, but not the domain.

Comment: Yaa ! with history API how can I accomplish this..

Comment: As I said, the history API will NOT let you change the domain.  It is the `history.pushState()` method that lets you change the URL path, but it has to be the same origin as the page that was loaded.

Comment: you can change path to redirect but cannot change the current url as browser will not allow you for this.. But why you want to do this?

Comment: @Alpesh - that is not quite correct.  Modern browsers will allow you to change the path with `history.pushState()` without redirecting.

Comment: Thanks !! I just need this knowledge for educational purpose only... how can we do alpesh ?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because of security measures in place. The URL is there to help identify the selected website. What you are trying to do is trying to spoof another domain name.

Imaging if any website could change its web address to that of a banking website where people type their account numbers and passwords.

Comment: How to just copy and paste text on addressbar  using javascript

Comment: @user3133175 - how many times do we have to tell you.  You can't copy/paste into the URL bar from javascript.